# gitversion mainline not correctly basing version off of mainline?

Tags: gitversion

I have a branch, let's call it features/feature_1

It has 5 commits since it was branched off of master. Its "increment" strategy is set to None. If I checkout master, it is version 3.18.1

If I checkout features/feature_1, it has version 3.5.1.

I am guessing that this is because 5 commits have occurred since it was branched from master, but this makes no sense. The increment strategy is "none", so it ought to be 3.18.1, the same as its source.

What is going on here?

EDIT: I have tried another experiment. If I checkout -b from `master`, I just get the version 3.5.1. Without any new commits. This is when `master` has got version 3.18.1. I cannot reconcile how this is possible.

```
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinor
assembly-file-versioning-scheme: MajorMinor
mode: mainline
tag-prefix: '[vV]'
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ci
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'
legacy-semver-padding: 4
build-metadata-padding: 4
commits-since-version-source-padding: 4
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
branches:
  master:
    tag: ''
    increment: Minor
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^master$
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - release
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: true
    is-mainline: true
    pre-release-weight: 55000
  feature:
    tag: useBranchName
    increment: None
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^features?[/-]
    source-branches:
    - master
    - feature
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  hotfix:
    tag: beta
    increment: None
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^hotfix(es)?[/-]
    source-branches:
    - master
    - feature
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
ignore:
  sha: []
commit-date-format: yyyy-MM-dd
merge-message-formats: {}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that you set both `is-release-branch: true` and `is-mainline: true` in your master branch configuration. The documentation says that `is-release-branch` should be set for branches that are release branches *according to GitFlow*, i.e. `release/1.0.0`. In GitFlow, `master` is not a release branch.

I also see that you have `source-branches` configured for your `master` branch. According to the documentation for **`source`**:

> [You can] give GitVersion a hint about [y]our branching workflows by telling it what types of branches a branch can be created from. For example, feature branches are, by default, configured to have the following source branches:
>
> `source-branches: ['master', 'develop', 'feature', 'hotfix', 'support']`

So in your configuration, you're saying that `master` can be created from either the `develop` or `release` branches. I think you meant to use `is-source-branch-for`.

According to the documentation for **`increment`**, maybe you should use `increment: Inherit`  for your feature branch configuration instead?

> The part of the SemVer to increment when GitVersion detects it needs to be increased, such as for commits after a tag: `Major`, `Minor`, `Patch`, `None`.
>
> The special value `Inherit` means that GitVersion should find the parent branch (i.e. the branch where the current branch was branched from), and use its values for `increment`, `prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version` and `tracks-release-branches`.

Now it may be that you want different behavior for `prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version` and `tracks-release-branches`, in which case, you can override those values in the `feature` branch configuration section.

Admittedly, the documentation for GitVersion is not very good or organized very well. I find that I just need to play around with my configuration a bit and try things out to really understand how it works. I hope that I've at least helped get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

for us, it worked bet in mainline mode (where the mainline is named `develop` here) to define the release branch as follows:

```
mode: mainline
assembly-file-versioning-format: '{Major}.{Minor}.{Patch}.{WeightedPreReleaseNumber}'
branches:
 develop:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    increment: Patch
    tag: unstable
    is-mainline: true
    pre-release-weight: 8000
  release:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    is-release-branch: false
    pre-release-weight: 1000
tag-pre-release-weight: 9500
```

with that, we alwys get `beta`-versions when building a release branch until a final version tag is set. The beta.revision will always be smaller than the unstable.revision and final tagged version will always have the highest revision.

that way, users of the unstable line always get the newest develop build, irrelevant if the release branch has more or less commits (e.g. changelog/documentation refinements).

normally, there will be no release branch at all but just tags for beta-versions and final releases on develop.

**Sample**
The `v1.2.0-beta.1` needed some tuning, so a release branch was created. the `v1.2.0-beta.2` was fine and was tagged as final `v1.2.0` and the release branch was merged back to develop.
A hotfix `v1.2.1` was released withou any beta shortly after.
[image: sample git commit tree for mainline dev]
(image via https://git-school.github.io/visualizing-git/)

Comment: update: I needed `tracks-release-branches: true` for my `develop` branch also, even in mainline mode!